# How to pass data into the template in Framework7?

Tags: meteor, html-framework-7

I trying to pass data that is fetched from the server to a popup.I tried doing something like this but its not working.Please help-

```
{
  path:'/merchant/:id',
  beforeEnter: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
    console.log(routeTo.params.id);
    Meteor.call('getOne',routeTo.params.id,(error,result) => {
      if (result) {
        resolve(
          {
            popup: {
              el:document.querySelector('#sample-popup')
            }
          },
          // Custom template context
          {
            context: {
              users: result,
            },
          }
        )
      }
    });
  } ,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#async-route), you use `resolve` callback wrong !

You can also read [this](https://blog.framework7.io/mastering-v2-router-958ea2dbd24f#dc7b) understand how to achieve this

Comment: Can u please help me this.I'm still not getting what is wrong

Comment: You can't pass `popup` into resolve function. For example, move the html for the popup to another file and add ` componentUrl: 'path-to-popup-file.html'` in `resolve()`